# Properties missing in TypeScript when strongly typing variable to kendo.mobile.Applicaiton

Tags: typescript, kendo-mobile

I'm using kendo mobile and typescript.  The pane property is missing.  I have my references setup correctly as other properties display as expected just not the pane property (and a few others).

```
var _app : kendo.mobile.Application = new kendo.mobile.Application();;

//then I try to do this but pane shows the red squiggly saying does not exist
if (_app.pane) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the definitions locally and send them a PR at a future point:

```
declare module kendo{
   export module mobile{
       interface Application{
            pane:any;
       }
   }
}

var _app : kendo.mobile.Application = new kendo.mobile.Application();;

// should be okay now 
if (_app.pane) {
....
}
```